# Activity Log in dashboard sonata admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, dashboard

I'm trying to implement activity log in the dashboard i.e. a notification in each row that says which entities have a change since the last login of a user.

To do it I'm thinking about overwrite the class AdminListBlockService and the template block_admin_list.html.twig

but i don't have yet clear how do it.

someone know a better way to do it?  if that is the better way, how can I achieve it?

thanks a lot!

ok

I found a better way... i have overwritten  only the block_admin_list.html.twig so:

//config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
          list_block:          AdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig
```

note the diference "SonataAdminBundle" and "AdminBundle"

next step add in the template:

```
{% if admin.activityLog() is defined and admin.isGranted('LIST') %}          
     <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list')>admin.activityLog</a>
{% endif %}
```

and finally create the logic for each Entity where i want the notification

```
//in the exempleAdmin

 public function activityLog(){

      // custom code $activity= ....

    return $activity;
 }
```

if someone know a better way to do it,  please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is override the template like this:

In your admin class:

```
// Configure our custom roles for this entity
public function configure() {
    parent::configure();
    $this->setTemplate('list', 'MyAdminBundle:CRUD:list-myentity.html.twig');
}
```

Then in your template you can do something like:

```
{# The default template which provides batch and action cells, with the valid colspan computation #}

{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig' %}

{% block table_body %}
    <tbody>
        {% for object in admin.datagrid.results %}
            <style>
                table tr.green-color td {background-color: #2BFF5D !important; }
            </style>
            <tr {% if changed %} class="green-color" {% endif %}>
                {% include admin.getTemplate('inner_list_row') %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: hi!! thanks for your answer!! perhaps i'm wrong but i thought this way worked for the list template from a unique entity, not in the dashboard comun dashboard where there are all the entites